# String Template for errors

Tags: c#, string, templates

I dont know if I am expressing the proper terminology here, so please correct me and I will update the thread properly.

I have a lot of error options and I would like a Template so I dont have to either retype the error string over and over, nor have a bunch of string + string ... in my code.  Here is what I mean:

```
if( reasonFailed == ReasonFailed.BAD_INPUT )
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed because: Bad User Input.  Please try again");
else if( reasonFailed == ReasonFailed.SERVER_RESPONSE_FAILED )
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed because: Server failed to respond.  Please try again");
else if( reasonFailed == ReasonFailed.INTERNAL_ERROR )
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed because: Internal Error.  Please try again");
...
```

I know I can put:

```
string beginningError = "Error: Failed because: ";
string endError = "  Please try again";

MessageBox.Show(beginningError + "error..." + endError);
```

but I was hoping for something more elegant, like:

```
string errorTemplate = "Error: Failed because: {0}.  Please try again";
MessageBox.Show(errorTemplate, "error...");
```

Anything available like this?

Comment: Consider using a switch statement as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yea yea ... this was just an example.  But yes, definitely a switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Format` to format your error:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format(errorTemplate, "error..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `String.Format` function ?

It is documented here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx